# Linq Expression for Any and Contains

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

I have to change linq query below to a dynamic expression in linq but I have a problem with `Any` and `Contains` methods.

```
List<string> set1 = new List<string> {"100", "400"};
List<MyObj> set2 = new List<MyObj>();
set2.Add(new MyObj() {name="a", code="100"});
set2.Add(new MyObj() {name="b", code="200"});
set2.Add(new MyObj() {name="c", code="300"});
set2.Add(new MyObj() {name="d", code="400"});
```

Sample query

```
var test1in2 = set2.Where(t2 => set1.Any(t1 => t2.code.Contains(t1)));

//Return value
{name="a", code="100"} and {name="d", code="400"}
```

How do I change this query into dynamic expression?

Comment: Why do you want to use dynamic expressions?

Comment: why is "How do I change this query into dynamic expression" so different from the title... do you have a problem with the existing code or you wanting to make it expression based. if so like the above says why

Comment: I have other section of code which use dynamic expression and this is just sample query that I also have to change to dynamic expression. My issue here is "Any" that I can't change to dynamic expression, any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I never use the dynamic query syntax, but if  you must, the following should work:

```
var queryResult = 
    from s2 in set2
    join s1 in set1 on s2.code equals s1        
    select s2;
```

Just for completeness the above can also be rewritten in the following expression; without using the slower `contains` and `any` operators:

```
var expressionResult = set2
    .Join(set1, s2 => s2.code, s1 => s1, (s2, s1) => s2);
```

Comment: If this addresses your question, please mark it as the solution. If not, then let me know and I'll be happy to help!